# Javascript 'onclick' fail in windows environment but works in linux environment

Tags: javascript, jsp

Simpy have a JSP based website tht runs on tomcat on a machine, and is used to configure some files on that machine.

Configuration save is achieved by, clicking Save button, which kicks off a restart servlet that runs a few scripts, redirection also included with an href..

The offending code:

```
<a onclick="if(confirm('Sava changes?')){window.location='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/restart.do'}" href="<%=request.getRequestURL()%>#">
    Save Changes
</a>
```

As stated in the title, works fine under linux environment but in windows environment, the page redirects fine but the restart servlet is never fired.

Any suggestions welcome guys

Comment: Are you sure it's a windows/linux distinction, and not a browser one (are you using the same browser on both? If so, which one?)

Comment: Also, if "the page redirects fine", it's most probably not a JavaScript issue. Track your network in browser devtools and check appserver logs, see what requests actually happen and who handles them. Also, make sure to `return false` from the onclick handler.

Comment: Are you changing the server environment from Linux to Windows or the browser environment? If the latter, are you using the same browser on both platforms? Which one?

Comment: I just [tested this](http://jsfiddle.net/JrxbW/) on a Windows environment and it worked just fine. Have your checked the output of `request.getContextPath()` to make sure it's what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onclick` handler, you're not doing anything to prevent the default action of the link, which is to follow the `href`. So although you're setting `window.location`, that's immediately being overridden by the browser following the link.

In old DOM0 style handlers (the kind you're using), you can prevent the default action of the link by adding a `return false;`. So:

```
<a onclick="if(confirm('Sava changes?')){window.location='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/restart.do'; return false;}" href="<%=request.getRequestURL()%>#">
    Save Changes
</a>
```

...or preferably:

```
<script>
function checkSave() {
    if (confirm('Sava changes?')) {
        window.location='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/restart.do';
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<a onclick="return checkSave();" href="<%=request.getRequestURL()%>#">
    Save Changes
</a>
```

...or even better, look into hooking up your JavaScript handlers via DOM2-style event handling instead ([`addEventListener`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener) on standards-supported browsers, [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE8 and earlier).

Answer (score 0):

Add a **return false** to the end of you if clause in your onclick event to prevent href from be excuted if the condition mathes:

```
 <a onclick="if(confirm('Sava changes?')){window.location='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/restart.do';return false;}" href="<%=request.getRequestURL()%>#">
```

Comment: I have added a **return false** to the if clause in the onclick event. this will prevent the link href from execution, so if your if clause works. the href will be ignored

Comment: and please revise your voting if possible